# [Android]Does Android System gerrentee the execution order of user defined Broadcast Receiver according to their android:priority?

Tags: java, android, service, broadcast

I designed a component(packed in .jar file) that contians a service, and this component could be contained in many applications(let's say there might be many applications who all have that component in them, are installed on one device). But only one instance of the component is expected to be exist on one deivce, that means if component in 'A' application has been started, the component in 'B' application is not going to be started during 'A''s lifecycle.

And maybe some day, there is another new application is installed on that device, but with a new version of that component. What I want is make sure the started component is always the newest version.

So, I want to use the BroadcastReceiver and android:priority as the solution(the new version will has a higher priority). But I have to make sure whether Android System gerrentee the sequence of excution(of BroadcastReceiver.onReceive) according to their priority.

Any one give me a hint? That would be very thankful:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: yes if you use ordered broadcast.

According [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) :

> Ordered broadcasts (sent with Context.sendOrderedBroadcast) are delivered to one receiver at a time. As each receiver executes in turn, it can propagate a result to the next receiver, or it can completely abort the broadcast so that it won't be passed to other receivers. The order receivers run in can be controlled with the android:priority attribute of the matching intent-filter; receivers with the same priority will be run in an arbitrary order.

So you must define the `android:priority` and you must send an ordered broadcast using : [Context.sendOrderedBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendOrderedBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String%29)

Note that, one of your receiver can even *abort*  the broacast so that it won't be propagated to the next receiver. (see : [abortBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast%28%29))